# Make webservice client compatible to newer servers

Tags: c#, enums, .net-3.5, wsdl, asmx

We have a .NET client that uses a proxy class (derived from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`) generated from a wsdl file by wsdl.exe.

Up to now we have a good compatibility between client and webservice for the most webservice changes.
An old client (with old proxy that is generated from an old wsdl file) would just not call the new webservice methods.
The only problem is an extension of an enum type (xsd.enumeration). This special enum is used in many `get...` calls.

## **Example**

### WSDL

```xml
  <xsd:simpleType name="Colors">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Red"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Blue"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Unspecified"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

### Proxy code generated from WSDL

```cs
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:archive.admin.services.ecm.opentext.com")]
public enum Colors { Red, Blue, Unspecified }
```

### Error

Client knows the *enum* `Colors` with values `Red`, `Blue` and `Unspecified`. If server returns a new enum value like `Yellow` we get the error:

```
Instance validation error: 'Yellow' is not a valid value for Colors.
Exception Class: System.InvalidOperationException
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderArchiveAdministrationService.Read2_Keys(String s)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderArchiveAdministrationService.Read6_ResultField(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderArchiveAdministrationService.Read7_ResultRecord(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderArchiveAdministrationService.Read10_invokeCommandResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
There is an error in XML document (1, 1557).
Exception Class: System.InvalidOperationException
StackTrace:
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

This error is correct because it is an ***enumeration***. But I looking for a pragmatic way to avoid this exception. You see in stacktrace that the exception is thrown by code that deserializes the response XML data to proxy's C# *enum*. Our own code can already ignore an unknown enum value like `Yellow`. But the .NET deserialization doesn't know our needs.

I have already found `SoapExtensions`. But then I would need to parse the whole XML content of every webservice response.

Do you have an idea/solution/workaround to avoid above exception?
Please don't warn me that "this is bad", "wsdl is a contract" and so on. I want just a pragmatic solution. :-)

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: The pragmatic answer is that if you treat a WSDL as a contract, you will not have these problems.

Comment: What exactly do you want the client to do about the server sending it data that it doesn't understand?

Comment: And why not just update the client? Update your web reference (or Service Reference, if you were using WCF as you should do), rebuild your client and redistribute.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know that ASMX is a legacy tech. But we had developed this client when ASMX was up-to-date. And now we are afraid of moving it to WCF because of the effort. The client has some 100,000 lines of code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Our customers does not have a DevStudio. They have a client installation. And if they want to update the client they would need to deinstall the old client version and install the newest client version. If customer have 10 old server and 1 new server and if he just want to look at one little information on new server we have 2 options: Either he must deinstall/install or we have compatibility to new servers.

Comment: But that makes no sense. In order to see the new information, they need to change the client. What you should do is create a second version of the server, that supplies the new information. Only those clients which require the new information need to be changed to use the new server.

Comment: The client shows 1000 "old" informations. If customer just wants to see one of them he could use old client. Another scenario where we wish the compatibility is for developers while development. For every mini feature on server all developers have to upgrade the client. And if client production failed (or client proxy is not yet updated by client team) they cannot connect to new server.

Comment: Of course we show a warning about incompatibility. The compatibility feature is only a workaround.

Comment: This is called "life". That's how it works. You can't reasonably make an old client interoperate with a new service, at least not in a meaningful way. For instance, if you changed from using an `enum` to using a `string`, then you could pass `Yellow`, but the client would not know what it means. That would be fine if all it wanted to do was to display the string.

Comment: Replacing `enum` by `string` is the best way. But server is developed by another team. I don't know if we can persuade them. :-)

Comment: In meantime... I tried SoapExtension and it works fine. The time for parsing the response stream is less than 15 ms. This is acceptable for a client.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with a SoapExtension.
I took the [TraceExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) sample and modified it so that every response XML is checked for unknown `enum` literals. If one is found the extension replaces it in XML by an unused `enum` literal (`Unspecified`).
The client code ignores the literal `Unspecified` then.

But one problem left: The webmethod needs to get the `SoapExtensionAttribute` (sub class). But the proxy class with that webmethod is generated code (from a *.wsdl). **So we need to set this attribute every time the code is generated.** The other option by configuration is imo not possible because we have a MMC Snap-In, a *.dll.